# Can I use _app.js to share data globally in my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a small chat app that will use sockets.
Thus I need to use both Context API and a global socket variable. This is my first project using Next.js and I'm not sure how the data flows here.
Beforehand, I used to pass props to the component with React router, however I came to realize that it's not possible with Next.js.
so, my question is whether I'm sharing the socket object correctly.
if that is not the case I would highly appreciate it if you can share with me a code snippet of the right implementation of Sockets utilizing Next.js

My _app.js file:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import '../styles/globals.css'
import UserRoom from '../context/state';
import { useState } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [userRoom, setUserRoom] = useState('');
  
  const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000', { transports : ['websocket'] });
  
  return(
    <UserRoom.Provider value={{userName, userRoom, setUserName, setUserRoom}}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserRoom.Provider>
   
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: You will create a new socket every time the component rerenders which can be multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `Yes you can`, you can share all global states inside `_app` file, but it will affect to all the components, including the server-side component and the client side, if something depends on the client it will throw an error because `window` is undefined.

and for the information, this is how next js Data-fetching props flow all work :

**Data Fetching > _app > components inside `pages`**

read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview)

Comment: Maybe I will rephrase my question.
I know I canuse it that way however will it be the correct way to share the socket object globally?